# Books with exercises or problems on the space of functions of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, bounded-variation, book-recommendation

I am studying BV space (the space of functions of bounded variation) by using Evans & Gariepy's book. However, there are no exercises for BV space, and I have no idea where I can find some.

Could you guys recommend me a book which has plenty exercise in BV space, as well as SBV space? (I know Luigi Ambrosio, Nicola Fusco, Diego Palla has some, but I wish to see more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a gentle introduction to functions of bounded variations, I recommend *A First Course in Sobolev Spaces* By Leoni, where Chapter 2 concerns one-variable BV space and Chapter 13 deals with several variables. There are many exercises throughout the text.

Special functions of bounded variation (SBV) is a recent topic, not even 30 years old yet. The book that you mention (*Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems* by Ambrosio, Fusco, Pallara) is the only comprehensive treatment of SBV that I know of, written by people who developed much of the subject. There are later books that use SBV as a tool, but they are more specialized and I would not expect you to find exercises there.

Comment: Thx I will check it out!

Comment: I second this. A nice feature is that there are two definitions of BV on open subsets of the real line and the book treats both carefully with a precise theorem stating their (basically) equivalence.